# Anonymous function without parameter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, anonymous-function

Could I define an anonymous function without parameter in Haskell?

I have a block of code repeated in several branches. Those code refer to several values outside.

Purpose 0: Define a function do the job in the codeBlock.

Purpose 1: Don't repeat codeBlock twice.

Purpose 2: Don't pass d1..d4 to the function. Avoid passing file and time even better.

```
f event d1 d2 d3 d4 =
  case event of
    (Modified file time) -> do
       codeBlock file time d1 d2 d3 d4 
    (Added file time) -> do
       codeBlock file time d1 d2 d3 d44
    _ -> return ()
```

Comment: If you want to use a block of code (with or without parameters, in Haskell or in another language) several times without repeating it, you generally need to give it a name.

Comment: You can just lift the repeated code into a `let`, i.e. you can turn `x = case y of P1 -> f largeCodeBlock foo; P2 -> g bar largeCodeBlock` into `x = let lcb = largeCodeBlock in case y of P1 -> f lcb foo; P2 -> g bar lcb`. Is this what you're after? (I'm happy to post this as an answer if yes.)

Comment: to give you a short answer: functions without parameters are called *values* ;)

Comment: Can you show us this code? It may depend on context.

Comment: Its really unclear what you are asking. Can you be more specific? Are you sure you know what "anonymous function" means?

Comment: @Cactus, the let statement is a fine solution for this case. I try to use the where statement. But it turns out to be wrong.

Comment: @highfly22 what's wrong with `where`? Did you place it at the proper scope level? If not it may be in scope only for one of the case branches (its indentation must be the same as the word "case")

Comment: @sinelaw, you are right. I added more spaces before where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a function without parameters (anonymous or otherwise). That's just a *value* (and in Haskell, *actions* like `main :: IO ()` are also just values).

For sure, a value can be defined anywhere (like a function); however if you want to reuse it in more than one place you should *not* make it anonymous but give it a (locally scoped) name:

```
f event d1 d2 d3 d4 =
  case event of
    (Modified file time) -> do
       defaultAction time
    (Added file time) -> do
       defaultAction time
    _ -> return ()
 where defaultAction time = do
           codeBlock file time d1 d2 d3 d4
```

BTW, `do` blocks with only a single statement are [equivalent](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) to just that statement alone, i.e. you could also write

```
f event d1 d2 d3 d4 =
  case event of
    (Modified file time) -> defaultAction time
    (Added file time) -> defaultAction time
    _ -> return ()
 where defaultAction time = codeBlock file time d1 d2 d3 d4
```

Comment: The second example gives "Not in scope: : ‘time’".

Comment: I see. So the anonymous function you've wanted doesn't even have zero parameters...